# SQL LIKE peculiarity-all characters or all digits

Tags: sql, sql-like

Just stuck on sql-ex #35 lesson, please suggest.

The database table consists of :
Product(maker, model, type)

Question:
In Product table, determine the models which consist only of digits or only of latin letters (A-Z, case insensitive). Result set: model, type of model.

My query looks like following:

```
SELECT model, type
FROM Product
WHERE
model LIKE '[0-9]%'
OR model LIKE '[a-z]'
OR model LIKE '[A-Z]'
```

Result is following: Incorrect.

Your query produced correct result set on main database, but it failed test on second, checking database. * Wrong number of records (more by 26)

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: You're only checking the first character of the `model` column, not the whole column.

Comment: this is lesson from sql ex site. DBMS is hidden, but I guess they use several to check query.

Comment: But `LIKE` works differently depending on the DBMS.

Comment: For instance, MySQL doesn't allow character ranges in LIKE, you have to use REGEX.

Comment: Answerers adding tags like sqlserver to justify an answer is particularly nefarious, no mention was made by OP that it was a particular dbms. If i'm wrong, please point me to the text that did so.

Comment: SQL (the query language) only supports the wildcards `%` for multiple characters and `_` for a single character. The expression `LIKE '[0-9]%'` means: Any value that starts with the literal string `'[0-9]'`

Answer (score 1):

Hints only since it appears to be coursework. The pattern `[0-9]%` will also match:

```
5#^*+}|>€?¥||
```

Assuming you have regex support, you may want to look into that, since it gives you a more expressive way to check data than the standard SQL `like`.

Answer (score 1):

**Edited and works perfectly:**

```
SELECT *
FROM Student
where ((TRY_cast(model as int) is not null ) or (model like REPLICATE('[a-z A-Z]',LEN(model))) ) and model<>''
```

Description: in this code which is suitable for sql server 2012 , because of Try_cast function the model value tries to be convert into int data type if the value has just one character so the operation will result null, so the result of `(TRY_cast(model as int) is not null` would be the values which are all digits.

---

second way: it is better and would be executable for most of rdbmss .

```
SELECT *
    FROM Student
    where (model like REPLICATE('[0-9]',LEN(model)))  or (model like REPLICATE('[a-z A-Z]',LEN(model))) ) and model<>''
```

Description: `model like REPLICATE('[a-z A-Z]',LEN(model)))` this code checks that all the characters should be a letter so don't worry about symbols like '&%#$#$@#@@#4' and etc...

Comment: That still only checked the first character

Comment: What DBMS is `TRY_cast` from? It doesn't work in T-SQL or MySQL. And how are you checking for letters?

Comment: When try_cast can't convert column to int , then it returns null.if the result is not null so it is a string that is convertible to int so it is all digits, and then a string which doesn't have digits has all characters.

Comment: But the question also requires you to check for letters.

Comment: Fixed your syntax error, but it's still not returning correct results: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/763c3/7

Comment: Thanks for your edit.The question says that the result should be the values which has all digits like '1243' or all characters like 'abs' is it true? that is all my understanding from question. the second part of my answer is showing the letter checking and check if there is no digits in the value.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I misunderstood, I thought it was "only digits and letters". But your solution allows `&&&&&`.

Comment: I've edited my post and if i miss something please add to characters.

Comment: You don't use comma delimiters in `[...]`, just put the list of characters. There are almost 200 characters that have to be in the set of non-letters and non-numbers, thousands for Unicode.

Comment: That's what I tried in my answer, but I deleted it because T-SQL doesn't allow you to use multiple ranges in one character set.

Comment: I think this is all in my mind and all symbols which is in my keyboard i founded.

Comment: You're missing hundreds of other special characters, like accented letters, currency symbols, other diacriticals.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server, I think you can use `PATINDEX()` function here.

Demo data:

```
create table tbl (model varchar(50))
insert into tbl (model) values ('1234'),('abcd'),('12sgb'),('£efr12')
```

Query (assuming you have only a-z, 0-9 characters in models):

```
Select model
From tbl
Where  patindex('%[0-9]%',model) = 0 or --Select models only with a-z
       patindex('%[a-z]%',model) = 0 --Select models only with 0-9
```

Results:

```
| MODEL |
|-------|
|  1234 |
|  abcd |
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8e6c2/9)**

Comment: Please have a look on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT *
FROM Student
WHERE model NOT LIKE '%[^A-Z]%' OR model NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'

Answer (score 0):

SELECT model, type FROM Product WHERE model NOT LIKE '%[^A-Z]%' OR model NOT LIKE '%[^0-9]%'

Right.

The result of Your query:

model   type

1121    PC

1232    PC

1233    PC

1260    PC

1276    Printer

1288    Printer

1298    Laptop

1321    Laptop

1401    Printer

1408    Printer

1433    Printer

1434    Printer

1750    Laptop

1752    Laptop

2113    PC

2112    PC

Answer (score 0):

you have to write the query like this

```
select model, type from product
where model not like '%[^0-9]%' or model not like '%[^a-z]%'
or model not like '%[^A-Z]%'
```